# How can I re-size multiple CMD windows using batch?

Tags: batch-file

I need to open 6 cmd windows for my Erlang work.
But.. I need to resize/move them.

Heres the 6 windows that will be opened:

```
start /d "C:\Users\**\Desktop\Erlang WorkingSpace\bin" erl.exe -setcookie talk -name server@127.0.0.1 
start /d "C:\Users\**\Desktop\Erlang WorkingSpace\bin" erl.exe -setcookie talk -name users@127.0.0.1
start /d "C:\Users\**\Desktop\Erlang WorkingSpace\bin" erl.exe -setcookie talk -name db3@127.0.0.1
start /d "C:\Users\**\Desktop\Erlang WorkingSpace\bin" erl.exe -setcookie talk -name db2@127.0.0.1
start /d "C:\Users\**\Desktop\Erlang WorkingSpace\bin" erl.exe -setcookie talk -name db1@127.0.0.1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can resize the current commandline window using the `mode` command:

```
mode 140,50
```

will give you 140 columns and 50 rows.

However you cannot do that from another commandline window. If you need certain size, you will need to put the .exe call into a batch file and call mode from within the batchfile before running the exe.

Comment: Interestingly, `mode /?` says nothing about such syntax (in XP SP3 anyway), but it works nevertheless, +1! I think, the arguments for `mode` could be passed to the batch file, which, in a way, would mean setting the size externally (from another command line window, as you put it). So, the idea about `mode` seems just great!

Comment: I think `mode 140,50` is just a shortcut for the syntax `mode con: cols=140 lines=40` which *is* shown through `mode /?`

Comment: It obviously is a shortcut to that, although that is not really obvious, if you see what I mean. :) Perhaps this is an older syntax, not promoted officially any more (yet still supported).